# XSLT recursively add numbers and use it in conditional check

Tags: xslt, recursion

I am facing an issue while adding values in a particular node and using that in a conditional check. My input xml is:

```
 <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure1</item>
        <item name="amount">100</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure2</item>
        <item name="amount">200</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure3</item>
        <item name="amount">300</item>
    </record>
Using xslt, I have to create an output which will look like:


<result>
        <entry name="Measure1">100</entry>
        <entry name="Measure2">200</entry>
        <entry name="Measure3">300</entry>
        //requirement starts here
        if sum of measure1 i.e 100 + measure2 i.e 200 + measure3 i.e 300 >=0
        <entry name="Measure4">m1 + m2 + m3</entry> 
        otherwise if sum of measure1 + measure2 + measure3 < 0, the element should be
        <entry name="measure5"> m1 + m2+ m3 </entry>
    </result>
```

I have tried recursive template call to add numbers but do not know how to get the output in a variable and use that in a conditional check. For e.g. in the above case, I want to add 100, 200 and 300 and check if 600 >=0. Its true and hence in the output xml, I only want to display measure4. 
If the total had been < 0, I only want to display measure5 and not measure4. Please help me gurus.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>

      <xsl:variable name="sum" select="sum(record/item[@name = 'amount'])"/>

      <xsl:variable name="n">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$sum >= 0">
            <xsl:text>Measure4</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>measure5</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>

      <entry name="{$n}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
      </entry>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <entry name="{item[@name = 'measure']}">
      <xsl:value-of select="item[@name = 'amount']"/>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<root>
  <record>
    <item name="measure">Measure1</item>
    <item name="amount">100</item>
  </record>
  <record>
    <item name="measure">Measure2</item>
    <item name="amount">200</item>
  </record>
  <record>
    <item name="measure">Measure3</item>
    <item name="amount">300</item>
  </record>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<result>
  <entry name="Measure1">100</entry>
  <entry name="Measure2">200</entry>
  <entry name="Measure3">300</entry>
  <entry name="Measure4">600</entry>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

This short and simple transformation (no `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSum" select="sum(/*/*/item[2])"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNewNum"
 select="count(/*/record) + 2 - ($vSum >= 0)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="cond"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="record">
  <entry name="{item[1]}">
   <xsl:value-of select="item[2]"/>
  </entry>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="cond" match="record">
  <entry name="Measure{$vNewNum}">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vSum"/>
  </entry>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a top element to make it a well-formed XML document, ad the last number increased with `1`):

```
<t>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure1</item>
        <item name="amount">100</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure2</item>
        <item name="amount">200</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure3</item>
        <item name="amount">301</item>
    </record>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<entry name="Measure1">100</entry>
<entry name="Measure2">200</entry>
<entry name="Measure3">301</entry>
<entry name="Measure4">601</entry>
```

**when in the above XML we change the last number to negative, so that the whole sum is now `-1`**:

```
<t>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure1</item>
        <item name="amount">100</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure2</item>
        <item name="amount">200</item>
    </record>
    <record>
        <item name="measure">Measure3</item>
        <item name="amount">-301</item>
    </record>
</t>
```

**the result now is again the correct and wanted one**:

```
<entry name="Measure1">100</entry>
<entry name="Measure2">200</entry>
<entry name="Measure3">-301</entry>
<entry name="Measure5">-1</entry>
```